# Silverlight MouseEventArgs GetPosition method

Tags: silverlight

I want to use GetPosition method in the place where no mouseeventargs available. I wonder why this method can be used only with MouseEventArgs?

I want something like this UIHelper.GetPosition

Comment: Is there another question hidden in here?  The answer to why such a method is not available other than during a mouse event is not one that many here could authoratively answer.  Even if you get answer I suspect you have a problem you'd like to solve and simply knowing "why" may not get you any closer to a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always add a static Point member on your root document and register a mousemove handler which does nothing but update that value.  (That's assuming you wanted a potential solution, and not an architecture discussion)