# Mouse in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, events, mouse, position

Is it possible to get the mouse position on Silverlight, without hooking on some MouseEvent? Like in WPF which is Mouse.GetPosition(object relativeTo).

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962700/silverlight-mouseeventargs-getposition-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word: no. Actually I need more words for SO's sake.

Comment: i have to run a method on render, which depends from the position of the mouse. how can i do this ? thanks